# Deploy Nodejs apllication on azure linux vm using azure release pipeline

Tags: node.js, linux, azure-devops

I am creating CI & CD pipeline for nodejs application using azure devops.
I deployed build code to azure linux vm using azure release pipeline, here I configured deployment group job.
In deployment groups I used extract files task to unzip the build files.
Unzip will works fine and my code also deployed in this path: `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/LearnCab-Manage(V1.5)-CI (1)/coreservices/ *.zip`
After that i would like to run the `pm2` command using azure release pipeline, for this task i take bash in deployment group jobs and write the command

```
cd $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/LearnCab-Manage(V1.5)-CI (1)/coreservices/*.zip
cd coreservices
pm2 start server.js
```

But bash not executed it will give exit code **`2`**.

Comment: Can you share the full bash script log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it will give exit code 2

This error caused by your argument are using parentheses `(` in the command at your first line. As usual, the parentheses is used as group. This could not be compiled as a normal character in command line.

To solve it, you need transfer the parentheses as a normal character with `\`:

```
cd $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/LearnCab-Manage\(V1.5\)-CI \(1\)/coreservices/*.zip
```

And now, `\(V1.5\)` and `\(1\)` could be translated into `(V1.5)` and `(1)` normally.

And also, you can use single or double quote to around the path:

```
cd "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/LearnCab-Manage(V1.5)-CI (1)/coreservices/*.zip"
```

Or

```
cd '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/LearnCab-Manage(V1.5)-CI (1)/coreservices/*.zip'
```